# Docker includes invalid characters "${PWD}" for a local volume name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, osrm

I want to install *OSRM* locally using the *docker* container under *windows*

I followed the steps in this [doc](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend/)

In the end I can not execute the necessary commands and I receive the following error :

[image]

Any suggestion will be very helpful for me, thank you !

Comment: I think in windows ${PWD} will not work

Comment: Please post formatted text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 12):

Path expansion is different in each shell.

For PowerShell use: `${pwd}`

For cmd.exe "Command Prompt" use: `%cd%`

bash, sh, zsh, and Docker Toolbox Quickstart Terminal use: `$(pwd)`

Note, if you have spaces in your path, you'll usually need to quote the path.

Also answered here: [Mount current directory as a volume in Docker on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

seems like the window command prompt does not interpret `$PWD`, you have to use gitbash or powershell I think. or another option is to use full path or current path.

> The flag `-v "${PWD}:/data"` creates the directory `/data` inside the
>   docker container and makes the current working directory `"${PWD}"`
>   available there. The file /data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf inside the
>   container is referring to `"${PWD}/berlin-latest.osm.pbf"` on the hos